# Switch addressbook error and skips input line

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement

So the moral of the programming assignment below is that I need to write an addressbook w/ first, last, address, city/state, zip. I must use a switch statement but no ioexception or buffered reader. LiFiAddressBook file is separate from LastFirstChapter10 (but linked in the same box below). It seems to compile correctly but it switches between an error of cannot use a Boolean in a switch statement, skips over zip code input to go to choose an option to search, and etc. I don't have the exact error right now as I'm at work and have no way to compile to output the exact error. Just looking for suggestions or corrections.

"LiFiAddressBook.java class
Instance variables:
First Name (string) Last Name (string) Street Address (string) City State (string) Zip Code (string)
addEntry method:
Get input for variables above. See sample in example at bottom.
search method:
Receive ArrayList as argument
Output Search Menu (see example at bottom)
Utilize a switch and search ArrayList for field specified.
Return index number if entry found or -1 if not found
display method:
Print results as shown in example at bottom."

LiFiAddressBook.java:33: error: incompatible types
        switch(isFound) {
               ^
  required: int
  found:    boolean
1 error

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastFirstChapter10
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        ArrayList<LiFiAddressBook> aBook = new ArrayList<LiFiAddressBook>();

        String searchStr = null;
        int field = 0;
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option = 0; ;

        for(int count=0; count<1 ; count++)
        {

                LiFiAddressBook ab = new LiFiAddressBook();
                System.out.println("Please Enter First Name:  ");
                ab.setFirstName(stdIn.next());
                System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name:  ");
                ab.setLastName(stdIn.next());
                System.out.println("Please Enter Street Address:  ");
                ab.setStreetAddress(stdIn.next());
                System.out.println("Please Enter City, State: ");
                ab.setCityState(stdIn.next());
                System.out.println("Please Enter Zip Code:  ");
                ab.setZipCode(stdIn.next());
                aBook.add(ab);

                System.out.println("Enter Search Option:\n"+
                    "1. First Name\n"+
                    "2. Last Name\n"+
                    "3. Street Address\n"+
                    "4. City, State\n"+
                    "5. Zip Code\n");
                option = stdIn.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter your search string: ");
                searchStr = stdIn.nextLine();

                int foundIndex = LiFiAddressBook.search(aBook, searchStr, 

field);
                System.out.println();

                if(foundIndex > -1)
                {

                    LiFiAddressBook abc = aBook.get(foundIndex);
                    abc.display();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("No entry is found.");

                } // end else

        } //end for

    } //end method

} //end class

  import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LiFiAddressBook {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String streetAddress;
  private String cityState;
  private String zipCode;

  public LiFiAddressBook() {

 }

  public LiFiAddressBook(String firstName,String lastName, String streetAddress,
      String cityState, String zipCode) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this.cityState = cityState;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;

  }

  public static int search(ArrayList<LiFiAddressBook> aBook, String searchStr, int field)

{

    if(aBook != null) {
      boolean isFound = false;
      for(int i=0; i < aBook.size(); i++) {
        LiFiAddressBook ab = aBook.get(i);
        switch(isFound) {
        case 1:
        //if(field == 1)
          isFound = ab.getFirstName().equals(searchStr.trim());
        case 2:
        //if(field == 2)
          isFound = ab.getLastName().equals(searchStr.trim());
        case 3:
        //if(field == 3)
          isFound = ab.getStreetAddress().equals(searchStr.trim());
                case 4:
        //if(field == 4)
          isFound = ab.getCityState().equals(searchStr.trim());
        case 5:
        //if(field == 5)
          isFound = ab.getZipCode().equals(searchStr.trim());
    }
        if(isFound)
          return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;

  }

  public void display() {
    System.out.println("First Name:  "+this.firstName);
    System.out.println("Last Name:  "+this.lastName);
    System.out.println("Street Address:  "+this.streetAddress);
    System.out.println("Zip Code:  "+this.zipCode);
    System.out.println("City, State:  "+this.cityState);
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getStreetAddress() {
    return streetAddress;
  }

  public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
  }

  public String getCityState() {
    return cityState;
  }

  public void setCityState(String cityState) {
    this.cityState = cityState;
  }

  public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
  }

  public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message or explain in more detail what is going wrong: What do you expect for what input and what do you actually get? Anyway, you might want to have a `break;` statement at the end of each `case`...

Comment: Error is this: LiFiAddressBook.java:33: error: incompatible types switch(isFound) { ^ required: int found: boolean 1 error 
Basically trying to make a switch but I guess I don't really understand them completely.

Comment: I understand your assignment a bit differently than you implemented it: I think you have not only to ask the user for the search string, but also for the field that should be searched (quote: search ArrayList for _field specified_). Only then using a `switch` statement makes sense: You switch for the field selected by the user and apply your code that you already have in your `case` section.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is not really meant for Arraylists.. I'm pretty sure it only does Integers and now in newer versions of Java Strings. I would recommend using a `for()` statement instead.... Not sure where else you would use the switch but be creative :)